# Create div overlay for image based on xml attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

I want to create a div overlay, set at 5% opacity, which creates a diagonal bounding box around each of the lines of text in this image.  I have the coordinates of each of the four points I need to draw the bounding box, which are encoded as attributes in an XML element which contains the text of individual line as its data. It seems to me that since I have the x,y coordinates for the four corners, I should be able to create the overlay -- but I cannot figure out what the proper syntax would be to mark out the div.  Someone suggested to me using the transform functions for CSS (which was the right call as I originally framed this question) but that sounds like I'd be basically writing eight separate pieces of css, one for each line -- which could get messy since there are potentially 118 pictures like this that I would be writing custom pieces of CSS for.

Am I wrong in thinking this can be done programmatically, and if not can someone point me at some methods for doing so?

[image: Image that I want to draw the overlay on]

Comment: can set the css with script such as jQuery `css()` method.  http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/89x4d/366/), with simple html markup:

```
<div class="image_box" data-cords="20,50,210,50,50,250,240,250">I am the text inside the div, I can be in several lines. It is important for text stay vertical and it is important the text to follow boundary box.</div>
```

Than do some script magic:

```
$.fn.skewText = function () {
    return this.each(function (i) {
        var thisText = $(this);
        var coords = thisText.data('cords').split(',');
        /* Calculate degree */
        var deg = Math.tan((coords[5] - coords[1]) / (coords[4] - coords[0])) * 57.2957795;
        /* Skew pixels for calculations */
        var skewVal = coords[4] - coords[0];
        /* Calculate position */
        var cssWidth = (coords[2] - coords[0] - skewVal) + 'px';
        var cssHeight = (coords[5] - coords[1]) + 'px';
        var cssTop = coords[1] + 'px';
        var cssLeft = (coords[0] * 1 + skewVal) + 'px'; /* Add a half of skew */
        /* Wrapp and apply styles */
        thisText.wrapInner('<div class="skew_padding" />').wrapInner('<div class="skew_text" />');
        var skewText = thisText.find('.skew_text');
        skewText.css({
            'transform': 'skew(' + deg + 'deg)',
                'top': cssTop,
                'left': cssLeft,
                'width': cssWidth,
                'height': cssHeight,
                'background': 'none rgba(0,0,0,.5)'
        });
        /* Now skew back each letter inside */
        var skewPadding = skewText.find('.skew_padding');
        var letters = skewPadding.text().split(' ');
        var newText = '<span>' + letters.join('</span> <span>') + '</span>';
        skewPadding.html(newText);
        skewPadding.find('span').css({
            'display': 'inline-block',
                'transform': 'skew(' + (-deg) + 'deg)'
        });
    });
};
$('[data-cords]').skewText();
```

That is possible with this css:

```
.image_box {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: yellow;
}
.skew_text {
    position: absolute;
}
.skew_padding {
    padding: 10px;
}
```